# Hanlde missing body property in post request with NestJs

Tags: post, error-handling, nestjs, class-validator

I would like to know what is the best way to handle or to prevent POST requests from a user with a missing body property.
For example, i have a sample DTO like this :

```
 export class SourceDto {

  id: string;

  name: string;

  description: string;

  address: string;

  agent_id: string;

  state: number;

  created_at: Date;

  updated_at: Date;
}
```

When sending a post request without the "name" property in the body I am getting a 500 error because my query needs the name property to not be null.
So my question is does NestJs also handle validations to validate if any of the body properties are missing? And instead of returning 500 errors without any info, return an error message that says missing name property?

Comment: read the docs https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation

Comment: Yes, I already read this thanks, do you have any idea?

Comment: so read it again. The docs shows what you need to do to set up a validation layer with the built-in `ValidationPipe` that replies with `400` if it fails

Comment: The docs only show you how to prevent the user to provide an empty value , but i want to prevent the user to NOT provide a value

Comment: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/#validation-decorators